# Convert a img src to file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC application to upload images to the server through a input and JQuery, this and the code:

**Jquery:**

```
function GuardarTicketsEntregados() {

    var imagefile = document.getElementById("imageFile").files[0];
    var cantidad = $("#txtCantidad").val();
    var nroSocio = $("#txtNroSocio").val();
    var descripcion = $("#txtDescripcion").val();
    var centroCosto = $("#cboListaCentrosCosto option:selected").text();
    var montoTotal = $("#txtMontoTotal").val();

    var listaTickets = [];

    var formData = new FormData();


    $(".ticket").each(function (i) {
        listaTickets.push(this.value);
    });
    formData.append("cantidad", cantidad);
    formData.append("listaTickets", listaTickets);
    formData.append("observaciones", descripcion);
    formData.append("nroSocio", nroSocio);
    formData.append("centroCosto", centroCosto);
    formData.append("montoTotal", montoTotal);
    formData.append("archivo", imagefile);
    $.ajax({
        url: "../TicketsCash/GuardarTicketsEntregados",
        traditional: true,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
        processData: false, // Not to process data  
        async: true,
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.correcto) {
                swal("Exito", data.mensaje, "success");
                document.getElementById('txtCantidad').value = 0;
                document.getElementById('txtMontoTotal').value = 0;
                document.getElementById('txtDescripcion').value = "";
                document.getElementById('txtNroSocio').value = "";
                document.getElementById('cboListaCentrosCosto').value = "No especifica";
                EscanearTicketsEntrega();
                //$('#modalModificarNivelExitoso').modal({
                //    backdrop: true
                //})
            }
            else {
                swal("Atencion", data.mensaje, "warning");
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            swal("Error", "Error al procesar la solicitud.", "error");
        }
    });
}
```

and the html:

```
            <input id="imageFile" type="file" name="imageFile" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
            <button id="btnEntregarTickets" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Entregar</button>
```

Now I want to take the picture with the pluing http://www.scriptcam.com/ therefore would have to take

```
    <img id="image" style="width:500px;height:500px;" />
```

Is there any way to convert the src of the image to a file so that I do not have to change the code in the controller?
What other options do I have?

Thank you so much

Comment: Are you trying to download image ?If so use <img src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>

Comment: If you tryting to img src url ,you can use - document.getElementById("image").src